# How to access SharedPrefernces in Repository in Android architecture components

Tags: android

I am new to android development, I was exploring android architecture components and wanted to use shared preferences in repository , but shared preferences require a application contexts , so wondering how to pass application context to repository because view model should not have any reference to the activity so wanted to figure out what is the best way to fetch data from shared preferences in android repository

Answer (score 0):

We have used Dagger DI approach in our project and tried injecting SharedPreferenceUtils in RepositoryImpl :

```
 @Singleton
public class SharedPreferenceUtils {

    //region Private Fields
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private final String TAG = SharedPreferenceUtils.class.getSimpleName();    
    //endregion

    @Inject
    public SharedPreferenceUtils(SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences) {
        this.mSharedPreferences = mSharedPreferences;
    }
}
```

Then inside AppModule we have provided SharedPreference instance as:

```
    public class AppModule {
@Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }
}
```

Then Simply inside our Repository we have used it as:

```
public class RepoImpl implements Repo{

@Inject
    SharedPreferenceUtils mSharedPreferenceUtils;
}
```

Hope this helps.